# InDesign: how to get first letter bigger in each word of a sentence?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, typesetting, formatting

How can i get first letter bigger in each word of a sentence?

[image: something like this in the image]

Comment: Can you please add more detail to the question.

Comment: You hold down `Shift` when you type it..?

Answer (score 11):

That looks like small caps are being used, so:

- select the sentence
- hit the 'Small Caps' button as seen below
- go to 'Type → Change Case → Title Case'. This will capitalize each word and then you'll have to lower case some of the wording by hand (*of*, *and*, *a*).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also automate this using two nested GREP styles in your paragraph style:
First set paragraph style as small caps, then set these 2 grep styles:

1. Change first letter of of each word to Cap
2. Change back to small caps all words in a serie that you'll define (use pipe sign 'OR' as separator)

If for some reason, you need to capitalize sometimes a word, just like "The" in the example below, you can just type it manually.
In option, you can add a third Grep style "Apply Capitalize" to text **^\w** to always capitalize first letter of the paragraph.

See example below: first para Normal, second para styled with settings as described.

[image]